# How do you calculate the total number of donuts sold?

Tags: survey

Let's say you're trying to calculate the total number of donuts sold in NYC in any given month, how would you go about doing this?

What would be the most efficient way? This is an open-ended question I got in an interview, meaning you could make assumptions if you want.

I froze up and couldn't think of any good way to do this, what do you think?

Comment: It all depends on the data you have available.

Comment: For what purpose, applying what criteria of accuracy? How is "efficiency" supposed to be conceived of or measured?  Is this intended to be a thought experiment or perhaps a design for a serious study?  During interviews you need to make sure you're communicating, so *asking questions* to achieve clarification is the very first response to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually something I have experience with!

For legitimate business' selling donuts, look for issued licenses according to the [NYC Department of Consumer Affairs](https://a858-elpaca.nyc.gov/CitizenAccess/) based on your criteria.

After establishing a list, I would recommend a random sample of the donut shops within the defined area of which you like to conduct your study, is it just limited to manhattan, or all of the boroughs?

Depending on the business population size, determine your sample size.

If you want first-hand data, you can literally go to each shop and count the number of donuts sold. But beware, this might be seen negatively.

If you want something easier, you can ask for their help via a survey. But don't expect a high response rate.

Extrapolate and estimate given different variables, weather, season, city events, price of inputs (like wheat and water cost), water quality, residential density, access to mass-transit (people like fast food), access to commercial stores (people get hungry when shopping). etc.

For off-the-street donut sales, I guess you can just start to canvass neighborhoods and conduct some fieldwork to determine the above.